# What are cheap options for an extra set of brake levers for mechanical disk brakes?

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, mechanical, brake-levers

A quick question. I want to have an extra pair of brake levers for my mechanical disk brakes set at a different position on my handlebar(s), and I want the whole upgrade to cost as little as possible. Ideally not more than 50$, at max 100$ (so no ultra-hightech sport competition-grade stuff). What are my options? So far I've discovered only the thing called ["Cross/Inline brake levers"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2ZgNrS7hSc) They seem like the thing, but it seems to me they are a bit limiting regarding where you can place them. Are there any other relatively cheap options?

**Edit:**
Sorry for confusion, I had to mention I don't have a typical road bike's or cyclocross bike's setup. I'm riding a hybrid bike, which has a butterfly bar as a main bar, and a couple of high curved horns attached at its left and right edge. Horns allow me to sit almost perfectly straight, and the main (butterfly) bar allows to lean forward for a bit more aggressive posture when riding over rough terrain. So I would like to be able to engage my brakes from both those main hands' positions.

Comment: Where else would you want to put them other than where you'd put cross levers?

Comment: Yup - those inline cyclocross levers as pictured are exactly what you want.  No need to fit them in pairs either.

Comment: A photo of your set up and main brake location may help.

Comment: Also please describe where you want the auxiliary brake lever. I assume you are using the standard setup, with brake/shifter at the closer mounting point.

Comment: @Mori-mori-mori this is a great question.  Can you please add a photo of your handlebar setup?

Comment: Assuming by "horns" you mean bar-ends, I ride on [these](https://www.evanscycles.com/ergon-gp3-grips-00120040) quite a lot on my hybrid, and rely on being able to get to my normal brakes within a sensible vision distance.  That means I don't use them in traffic or on very windy paths, but changing hand positions is quick

Comment: "Cheap options" and "brakes" maybe aren't the best combination?

Answer (score 7):

Presumably you have drop bars. Inline brake levers are your only choice. The only places to mount extra levers on drop bars are tops. With inline levers installed you can reach levers from the drops, hoods and tops, so you really don't need levers anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks, @argenti-apparatus , but that's seem like possible problem - the fact you only can install inline levers at "tops". I also don't have drop bars, instead I have a butterfly bar and a couple of high curved horns attached at its left and right edge. Horns allow me to sit almost perfectly straight, and the main bar allows to lean forward for a bit more aggressive posture when riding over rough terrain.

Comment: Where are your main brake levers positioned? The only way to get additional levers is with 'interrupter' types that must be positioned on the brake cable path. On drop bars that means the tops.

Answer (score 1):

Problem Solvers make a ["cable doubler"](https://problemsolversbike.com/products/brakes/12_-_8816o) to allow two separate levers to actuate one brake. You might just be able to find them within your budget for a pair, but you'd also need to buy brake cables and possibly inline adjusters.

They also make one to actuate two brakes with one lever, so be sure to buy the right opne if you go down this route.

Comment: Thanks Chris! That's really a very interesting option, and it seems it's the one which won't place much restrictions on where I'll be able to place the levers too!